# Changing from xaml design into C# coding

Tags: c#, xaml, wpf-controls

I am currently try to programatically get the ListBox
I tried to find many ways but, I can't make this works.

Here is the xaml part of code:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="PeerList" Margin="10,10,0,10">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" Margin="40,0,0,0"/>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I want this same operation to be done programatically.

Someone familiar to XAML to C# help me to solve this. .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Programatically display the name of the peers in this list means follow @Hiệp Lê Answer.

Otherwise if you want only to get the name of the peers. Just follow this.

```
void SearchPeers()
 {
     List<string> name = new List<string>();
     var peers = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();
     for(int i=0;i<peers.Count;i++)
     {
       string peerName = peers.DisplayName;
       name.Add(peerName);
     }
 }
```

This will get you the name of the peers available.

Answer (score 2):

It is something like this

```
ListBox listbox = new ListBox();
DataTemplate dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
FrameworkElementFactory elementFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
elementFactory .SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("DisplayName"));
dataTemplate.VisualTree = elementFactory;

listbox.ItemTemplate = dataTemplate ;
```

Comment: I can't use FrameWorkElementFactory in my Visual Studio 2012 for windows Phone8. Is that Particular Functionality is only available for Ultimate Version????

Comment: FrameWorkElementFactory was introduced in .NET 3.0 and is available in all version of Visual Studio.

Comment: @Stewbob I am currently using Visual Studio 2012 Express Edition. I tried typing FrameworkElementFactory. But it doesn't show that option in my editor. Image for this scnario is edited in the question above itself

Comment: @Ethan, FrameworkElementFactory is available in 2012 Express (that's what I'm using now).  It is in the System.Windows namespace and is found in the PresentationFramework.dll.  Make sure you have a Reference to that dll and that you have the proper 'using' statement at the top of your class.  C# intellisense does not display every possible object, only those that are in the namespaces being used by your class.

Comment: @Stewbob Thanks for Reply. I got it. Is that possible to get the value that I ll get dynamically from the textblock.?(i.e: I will get the name of peers in the TextBlock. So, I need to assign that Name inside the textblock into some variable. then i can use that name)

Comment: It will bind the textblock TextProperty with the "DisplayName" Property, just look at the object in the list.